# Duplicate Documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoid3

I'm running into an issue where I'm sporadically having duplicate documents inserted into my MongoDB collection. It's only happened a handful of times and, in all cases, the duplicates are created within the same second as the original. My original guess was that I needed to add a unique index on a field, but I'm not sure that would necessarily prevent the duplicates being created nearly simultaneously, though maybe I'm overthinking that.

Is there any possible reason I could be seeing duplicate documents in MongoDB other than the lack of a unique index?

Comment: Have you considered using upsert instead of insert? This may circumvent the duplication on an insert by updating the original document with identical data.

Comment: I have and I'm evaluating how best to implement it with the way my code is currently pieced together.

Comment: Can you post an example of the code that is not working for you?

Comment: Ok, so a little more information I gleaned after digging a bit - it appears that multiple requests with the same data are hitting the database concurrently. The condition I'm using to look up whether the document exists or not is located in a sub-document that may not have necessarily been created yet. In this instance, I think moving the lookup field out of the sub-document and into the parent and indexing on that will prevent this issue in the future. Thoughts @JoshC.?

Comment: Sounds like a good lead.

Comment: while a unique index on some field can prevent a duplicate, if the logic of your application is correct, there should never BE a duplicate.  Probably some combination of upsert and using a different query predicate for the update statement would make it so.